# Simple example of libsoup client

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, glib

I'm trying to use libsoup in my program to download a file from Internet.
All I need(currently) is simply pass the url to libsoup and get the file downloaded to /tmp/ directory.

Basically my program looks like:

```
Download d;
d.get("http://test.com/sample.mp3");
```

I googled for simple example of libsoup but with no luck, maybe [Soup Client Basics](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/libsoup-client-howto.html) is a good start, but I'm afraid it is not straightforward for me as a new (glib) starter.

Can anyone share a simple hello world like program using libsoup client?

Comment: Maybe I was not describing well in my question. My question is how to use libsoup to get a url, and the expect answer is a simple libsoup code snippet that a new libsoup user can start with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, finally I worked out a simple version, as below.

```
g_type_init();
SoupSession *session = soup_session_sync_new();
SoupMessage *msg = soup_message_new ("GET", "http://mine.com/test.txt");
soup_session_send_message (session, msg);
fwrite (msg->response_body->data,
        1,
        msg->response_body->length,
        stdout);
```

This code is fairly straightforward, it gets `test.txt` from `mine.com` and print it out on the console.

Comment: I'd like to keep this for reference, if someone(like me) needs a quick start and simple example.

Comment: Upvoted, but I wish that you had shown the necessary #includes.